Why in VS 2022 components loaded in different position and sizes?
In Windows forms app when I open the solution I find the form components loaded in different position and sizes. Why is that ?
VS 2022 Community and Windows 11

Do you mean that the controls in the form are positioned and sized differently every time you open the solution? I tested it and I don't have such a problem. So can you provide me with a screenshot of your issue so that I can understand your specific situation?

it appear this happen because of installing third party components

So that's how it is. Many third-party components do make it easier to use. You can reinstall these components or try on a different machine. This way you can determine whether the problem comes from these components or from Winform itself.
